# Saving Form Data to Custom Table

Tags: forms, symfony, save, entity, magento2

I have a form that links to a controller and my goal is to save the data into my custom `vendor_module_table`

I've come across a few posts online on how to do. My problem with the provided solutions is that they all use **object manager** - and this to me feels like a bad practice. Especially when M2 is based on Symfony where I can just call a pre-built save/add function to my controller relating to my form and it just works.. has Magento2 tailored something for this?

```
public function execute()
{
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        $customerId = $post['customer_id'];
        $make = $post['make_id'];
        $model = $post['model_id'];
        $year = $post['year_id'];

        # to do - add insert
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Success!');

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/module/controller/add');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

E.g. code from my Symfony project:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    # set non-form fields
    $category->setApproved(0);
    $category->setCreatedTs(new \DateTime());

    try {
        # this is how Symfony saves data to a table
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Category Submitted for Review.');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'Something went skew-if. Please try again.'. $e->getMessage(). '- ' .$e->getCode());
    }

    return $this->redirectToRoute('category_list');
}
```

I went through [the docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/persistent-entities.html) and found this, but it doesn't have a clear example on how to implement. I came across a few posts on Magento SE and it's been advised to **not use** due to it being an incomplete feature. What are the alternatives / correct way to do this?

Comment: You could probably use a raw SQL or DQL query to add data without using the ORM.

Comment: @A.L yeah, that's probably a better way to do it, currently using _objectManager and it seems to mimic some of the behaviour of the ORM but... so many posts say it's bad practice etc. I get so confused with the M2 community xD

Comment: @treyBake using ORM is considered as bad practice in high performance/high load/hard to cache actions because it's give you more abstraction layers which are great for productivity but bad for performance aspect. My questions are a) you want to uses Doctrine(ORM) at all? If yes maybe look at DBAL b) Your problem is more about performance or good practices in productivity?